# Training model for image classifier on RockPaperScissors.zip file using Tensorflow and Keras

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, keras-layer, conv-neural-network

I tried to make an image classifier for RockPaperScissors.zip file and i had trouble in training the model. Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

!wget --no-check-certificate \
  https://dicodingacademy.blob.core.windows.net/picodiploma/ml_pemula_academy/rockpaperscissors.zip \
  -O /tmp/rockpaperscissors.zip

import zipfile,os
local_zip = '/tmp/rockpaperscissors.zip'
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(local_zip, 'r')
zip_ref.extractall('/tmp')
zip_ref.close()

base_dir = '/tmp/rockpaperscissors'
train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'rps-cv-images')
validation_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'rps-cv-images')

os.listdir('/tmp/rockpaperscissors/rps-cv-images')

train_rock_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'rock')
train_paper_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'paper')
train_scissors_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'scissors')
validation_rock_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'rock')
validation_paper_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'paper')
validation_scissors_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'scissors')

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        rotation_range=90,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        shear_range = 0.2,
        zoom_range = 0.2,
        validation_split = 0.2,
        fill_mode = 'nearest')

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size=(100, 100),
        batch_size=9,
        color_mode = 'rgb',
        shuffle=True,
        subset = 'training',
        class_mode = 'categorical')

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_dir,
        target_size=(100, 100),
        batch_size=9,        
        color_mode = 'rgb',
        shuffle=False,
        subset = 'validation',
        class_mode = 'categorical')

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(100, 100, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(loss ='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer= tf.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics= tf.metrics.Accuracy()
)

model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=25,
    epochs=15,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=5,
    verbose=2)
```

When i tried to train my model it says InvalidArgumentError:  Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [9,3], In[1]: [512,1]     [[node gradient_tape/sequential_2/dense_5/MatMul (defined at :5) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_8077]Function call stack:train_function. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to first think about what you will like to achieve. The task at your hand is to classify images in three different classes i.e rock, paper, or scissors.

So, your last layer should have three neurons one for each class. So the last layer will be as follows:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
```

I ran it on my box with this change your code should run.

Comment: @Fairuz Amira If the solution helped you, I would suggest to mark the solution as accepted so that others can be benifitted from the answer.